# No index.html page, issue in hosting

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I'm making a website, which is a forum. I'm doing this for the first time.

I've uploaded some content on 000webhost for testing my website through FTP. The problem is, there is no index.html file there, but there is an index.php file there.

It works perfectly on localhost. What should I do?

The error is webpage is not available.

Here is my config file setting as I used to do it in local host .. is there any problem there ?

```
define('MYSQL_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1'); 
define('MYSQL_USERNAME', '1234');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'demo');
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', '1234');
```

Comment: contact your web host for support.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty poor web hosting provider if index.php isn't recognized.

Comment: If you visit www.yourwebhosturlhere.com/index.php does your page come up?

Comment: @Charlie74 .. it is not showing up anything .. same error The error is webpage is not available.

Comment: I believe you can contact your support team about this issue. Have you setup your own default page correctly?

Comment: how to setup that own default page @DouglasThomas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the service you are using always listens for an `index.html`,  so I see you only have three options:

1. Contact your web hoster and ask how to change the main page
2. Make an `index.html` page, and have it redirect to `index.php`
3. Make an `index.html` page, and make an `iframe` in it with an `index.php` `src`

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard did this solve your problem?  If it did, you can mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

What error is it throwing exaclty? a 404 error?

Your index.php file is in the root directory?

Could you provide the web address?

Most of the time your localhost installation will be different from the web hosting you are using. And there are a lot of things that could be the problem.

Comment: http://ehm.host22.com/

Comment: please see the edited question . I have done phpmyadmin config file settings as stated above